# Quarkus / Keycloak - How to mock a Keycloak server in tests

Tags: testing, mocking, keycloak, quarkus

I'm using Quarkus 1.7 and KeyCloak 10.0.0

I cannot find resources of how to mock Keycloak server.
Because test cannot start if Quarkus do not find a Keycloak server.

It will be helpful to have more informations

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a section about [integration testing](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-oauth2#integration-testing) using Wiremock in the quarkus OAuth2 security guide.

Comment: I found another solution with Testcontainer